# VB.net Insert Environment.NewLine at 20 characters

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, insert, character

Well I have been able to figure this out but what I want to do is make my string have a new line after 20 chars. I know how to find how many chars the string has but not how to insert environment.newline at 20 chars.

I am using this to find the string length

```
If string.Length > 20 then
'Need to be able to insert environment.newline at 20 chars
Else
'Normal string
End If
```

Comment: What if the string has 70 characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If string.Length > 20 Then
                sTest = sTest.Insert(19, Environment.NewLine)
            End If

EDIT:

I think the index should be 19, or it could be 20, you might need to experiment with that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a loop: (Tested)

```
For index As Integer = 20 * (str.Length \ 20) To 0 Step -20
    str = str.Insert(index, Environment.NewLine)
Next
```

If the string can be very long, you should use a StringBuilder instead.

Comment: If I am using a listbox how could I make it insert the rest of the line like this.

Listbox1.Items.Insert(1, otherpartofline)

Comment: You can call `Substring(index, Math.Min(index + 20, str.Length))` inside the loop.